# What is the best way to take iterate an array of objects and put them into individual factory functions?

Tags: javascript

For example, say I have `data = [{car: "ford", year: "1982"}, {car: "toyota", year: "1999"}]` .

```
  //factory function
  function Car(type, year) {

     return {
        type,
        year,
        identity() {

           return "I am a " + year + " " + type

        }

     }  

  }

  let arr = []
  data.forEach((x) => {

     // would this be the correct way to turn these into factory function 
     // objects?
     arr.push(Car(x.car, x.year))

  })
```

Is there a better way of doing this so that each Car() has a variable associated with it?

Comment: Take a look to `Array.prototype.map()`.

Comment: As @AdrianoRepetti said, take a look at `Array.prototype.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: What kind of variable names were you thinking of? `ford1982` for example?

Comment: so just map through it instead of forEach and then `return Car(x.type, x.year)` so that it returns a new array with that data?

Comment: @Andy In that case, I can just make the variable `x.type + x.year = _____` , right?  I was actually thinking of passing in an index and just calling them `Car + index`

Comment: Just a quick note, your not using a feature of Javascript called prototype (A kind of class).  What this means here is that every instance of Car you create, you will be duplicating the function `identity()`.  For something as small as this it's not likely an issue.  But if your Car function becomes big, with lots of functions, then this approach is not ideal.

Comment: thanks for pointing out Keith.  Can I maintain usage of factory functions and add an identity prototype without switching over to Class usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you want your variable names to be meaningful.

You could assign the objects to another object with the car + year as the keys. I've used [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here to iterate over the dataset and create the new object. (I've also made a couple of other changes to the code.)

```js
const data = [{car: "ford", year: "1982"}, {car: "toyota", year: "1999"}];

function Car({ car, year }) {
  return {
    car,
    year,
    identity() {
      return `I am a ${year} ${car}`;
    }
  };
}

const cars = data.reduce((obj, { car, year }) => {
  const id = `${car}${year}`;
  obj[id] = Car({ car, year });
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(cars);
console.log(cars.ford1982.identity());
```

If you just want to have an `id` instead, as your comment indicates, you could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data and inject the iteration index into the data instead. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array of objects. You can then use array methods like [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to pick out cars based on their properties.

```js
const data = [{car: "ford", year: "1982"}, {car: "toyota", year: "1999"}];

function Car({ id, car, year }) {
  return {
    id,
    car,
    year,
    identity() {
      return `I am a ${year} ${car}`;
    }
  };
}

const cars = data.map(({ car, year }, index) => {
  return Car({ id: `Car${index}`, car, year });
});

console.log(cars);
console.log(cars[0].identity());
console.log(cars.find(car => car.id === 'Car1').identity());
```

Comment: thanks Andy.  Isn't iterating with a forEach and pushing into an empty array doing the same thing as well?

Comment: `forEach` changes/mutates the array, `map` creates a new one from/doesn't mutate the array. As you get into it you'll find modern functional JS is all about non-mutation of data.

Comment: interesting!  It mutates the original array, `data`, even if I'm just reading from it and pushing into a new empty array, `let arr = []` ?

Comment: Sorry, no. Not if you're pushing into an empty array. (I should read comments properly.) But you do use a for/loop or `forEach` if you want to amend an existing dataset.

Comment: Glad I made sense in the end :)

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, those strings between the backticks are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) @Curly .

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{car: "ford", year: "1982"}, {car: "toyota", year: "1999"}];

function Car(type, year) {

     return {
        type,
        year,
        identity() {

           return "I am a " + year + " " + type

        }

     }  

  }

// Use Map. Map iterates over your array, at each
// element it will call the supplied callback argument
// with the current element. Whatever your function returns
// will be mapped to a new array
// at the same index as the element passed to your callback

const arr = data.map(({ car, year }) => Car(car, year))

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks!  Is it any less efficient if I iterated with the `forEach` and pushed them into an array?  Isn't it essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: Here's a jsperf test I found, https://jsperf.com/loop-vs-map-vs-foreach map. Map ran faster than forEach + push. However, a plain for loop ran faster than bother methods. The real benefit to map, is that it returns an array and allows you to chain methods, later if you so chose.